# How do I run a websocket and discord.py bot concurrently?

Tags: websocket, discord.py, python-asyncio

I want to run a websocket concurrently with my discord.py Bot.

I hope someone is able to help out with that.
Thanks in advance.

Code for **client.py** (testing websocket):

```
import asyncio
import websockets

uri = 'ws://localhost:8000'

async def send_message():
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        message = "msg"

        await websocket.send(message)
        print(f"[ws client] message  > {message}")

        #answer = await websocket.recv()
        #print(f"[ws client] answer < {answer}")


asyncio.run(send_message())
```

code for **main.py** (Websocket/Bot):

```
# --- websockets ----

async def response(websocket, path):
    message = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"[ws server] message  < {message}")

    
# --- start ---
async def serve():
    print('running websockets ws://localhost:8000')
    server = await websockets.serve(response, 'localhost', 8000)
    await server.wait_closed()


# - discord -
client = Client()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    info_logger.info(f"starting Discord Bot!")
    asyncio.run(serve())
    client.run(os.getenv("BOTTOKEN"))
```

What I tried before since most of the people were using that was:

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete()
```

This however does not work anymore since I am getting a deprecation warning...

After reading through several posts I was only ever able to run one of the two but not both in one loop.

Threading also doesn't work since they are both async and would throw an error that they can't be run in threads.

Comment: what version of discord.py are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Use [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) to run a coroutine *"in the background"*.

```py
# --- websockets ----

async def response(websocket, path):
    message = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"[ws server] message  < {message}")

    
# --- start ---
async def serve():
    print('running websockets ws://localhost:8000')
    server = await websockets.serve(response, 'localhost', 8000)
    await server.wait_closed()


# - discord -
client = Client()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    info_logger.info(f"starting Discord Bot!")
    asyncio.create_task(serve())  # <-- instead of asyncio.run
    client.run(os.getenv("BOTTOKEN"))
```

Comment: When I do that I get the error that serve was never awaited. 
Although I don't see what else would have the need to be awaited.

Comment: need the whole traceback, add me on discord @SomeRandomGuy kwieeciol#6035